# Sequence of moods

Tags: future-tense

*1. If you **would/'d** do me this favour, I **will/'ll** be very grateful to you.*

*2. If you **would/'d** do me this favour, I **would/'d** be very grateful to you.*

*3. If you **will/'ll** do me this favour, I **will/'ll** be very grateful to you.*

According to my textbook: 1st is wrong but 2nd and 3rd are correct. I don't understand why. Also if there's any subtle difference between 2nd and 3rd, do let me know.

And also what about this one 4. *If you **will/'ll** do me this favour, I **would/'d** be very grateful to you*. -- Is this correct or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your book is right in theory, but wrong in practice.

First, note that we don't usually use the modal *will* in conditionals:  we don't say *If
it will rain, then ...*

We can do so when it has the meaning of "be willing to". So we can say *If he will go, then...*; but this has a different meaning from *If he goes, then ...*. It suggests that there is something about his willingness to go that is in doubt: perhaps it is a difficult journey, or we know he is busy.

In the same way that we can make *If he goes* into an *irrealis* (counter-factual) conditional by putting the verb in the past, *If he went*, we could in theory put that modal in the past for the *irrealis*, so *If he would go* meaning *If he was willing to go*; but in practice, that use is not very common. (Some people say *If he would go* to mean *if he went*, but that is different).

So, in principle, from what your book says *If you will do me this favour* is *realis*, and must be followed by a non-past *I will be grateful*, and *If you would do me this favour* is *irrealis*, and must be followed by a "conditional" (future in the past) *I would be grateful*. That is where the book's argument comes from.

Where this falls down in practice is that *If you will* and *If you would* are actually used as progressively more tentative (and so, more polite) ways of requesting something, so I don't believe that the claim the book makes holds up. The difference in the second clause (*will* or *would*) is about *realis* or not, i.e. how likely the other person is to agree to do the favour. But the difference in the first part is in practice more about how tentative and deferent the speaker is being in requesting, and not correlated with being *realis* or not.