# Chief vs Chiefest

Tags: difference

Sentence: *"Happiness is the **chief/chiefest** aim of mankind"*

According to my textbook(common mistakes in english) "chief" is correct here. {And there's no reason given.}

So, how to decide between these two?

Comment: You find _chiefest_ in older literature, but it isn't used today.

Comment: You're damn good at english language. Grateful to learn from people like you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Chiefest* is not a word in common use (the iWeb corpus has 955 instances, against 712499 of *chief* as an <s>adverb</s> adjective). It is only used today as a deliberate archaism.

I suggest you do not use it.

Comment: I like to hear your comments on this one: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/273171/sequence-of-moods

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, [chief](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/chief) means

> Most important.

and hence "chiefest" would mean "most most important."  This would make sense only in a discussion where you had a group of chief things, and then singled one out as the "chiefest," and is not generally used today